Proper replacement for old RockShox Judy C (2002) lower leg seals?
I have an old RockShox Judy C from 2002 (year stamped into fork). The seals for the lower legs are damaged - I removed them measured them but I cannot find a proper replacement or rather I am not sure which is the right one.
Measurements are:

outer diameter (which is pushed into the lower legs): 36 mm / 14.17 in
inner diameter (through which the upper legs are pushed): 28 mm / 11 in

Does anyone have a clue what might be the right replacement seals?

Hi, welcome to bicycles.  Do you mean 36 mm OD/28 mm ID?  36 cm seems completely wrong.

@DavidW it's almost certainly mm

@PaulH The only reason I didn't immediately edit the question is because the imperial measurements agree with the unit of centimetres.

Searching  “28mm wiper seal” will bring up local shopping results.  E.g https://www.performancebike.com/rockshox-dust-wiper-foam-ring-kit-28mm-sid-judy-pilot-dart-11.4307.250.000/p310389
